# Wrap imported file with code before passing to bash/shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I have an npm script though I think this would apply to any bash command:

```
node file.js
```

The content of `file.js` for the purpose of the question might be:

```
console.log('hello')
```

I would like to wrap the content of `file.js` in some code so that the final "content" is:

```
console.log('start')
console.log('hello')
console.log('end')
```

Right now I have the start/end stuff in a separate file which is the one I call and it in turns, imports the `file.js` file

```
// wrapper.js
const foo = import('./file.js') 
console.log('start')
foo() // or whatever...
console.log('end')
```

Then I call it:

```
node wrapper.js
```

This approach works but I am trying to eliminate the wrapper file and pass the content directly - Essentially concatenate 2 strings with content of a file and then have the `node` utility accept that like a file. (note that this is not specific to node cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**: Charles Duffy's comment recommends a simpler solution if you just want to wrap a file and don't need anything more complex than that.

```
{ 
 echo "console.log('start')" 
 cat ./file.js
 echo "console.log('end')"
} > ./wrapped.js
```

---

You can use `cat` for this.

```
printf '%s\n' "console.log('hello')" > ./file.js
cat <( printf '%s\n' "console.log('start')" ) \
     ./file.js \
    <( printf '%s\n' "console.log('end')" ) \
    > ./wrapped.js
cat ./wrapped.js
# outputs:
# console.log('start')
# console.log('hello')
# console.log('end')
```

This utilizes two [process substitutions](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (the `<( command )` syntax) to create temporary files containing the content you want to wrap around your script, then concatenates the three files together into a single file.

If you don't want to write the concatenated data out to a file, you could wrap the whole thing in another process substitution and pass it directly to your command in whatever manner it takes files.

```
node <(
cat <( printf '%s\n' "console.log('start')" ) \
     ./file.js \
    <( printf '%s\n' "console.log('end')" )
)
```

Comment: Definitely an entirely workable approach. Of course, `{ echo "console.log('start')"; cat ./file.js; echo "console.log('end')"; } >wrapped.js` would work just as well, and with compatibility with baseline `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Yeah that's easier than what I have, I'll add it. Probably the only reason to do anything else is if you need something file-like but don't want to actually write a file for some reason.